# back Button issue...and logout button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have searched lot on google for this. I got all the code but that code doesn't work. I created a logout button and on button's click redirecting user to logout page...but further things don't go well.

here is code for logout page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();  

}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + "?ReturnUrl=loginAcc.aspx";
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);

}
```

**Edit**: The Following Exception occurs: The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL: `/MailFormat/login.aspx`

Comment: Can you elaborate on the **further things** ?

Comment: *"further things don't go well"*? What is the specific problem?

Comment: What does "further things don't go well" mean in detail?

Comment: The Following Exception Occurs          =====  The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /MailFormat/login.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any timer control. Do you have a timer control on your page and is it enabled, so that the `Timer1_Tick` will be fired?

Answer (score 0):

try with below code.

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
```

FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() is neater. You should have a defaultUrl attribute set in your Web.config, ie `<forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx" />`

Comment: Where Can I set this tag in web config..Plz let me know

Comment: <configuration>
   <system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx">
 </forms>
   </authentication>
   </system.web>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Session and Authentication are two different things , which you need to sync on log out. I think Logout  Page_Load you should do 
FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); and then clear the session.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this query===I added a javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
function disableBackButton()
{
window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
window.onload=disableBackButton(); 
window.onpageshow=function(evt) { if(evt.persisted) disableBackButton() } 
window.onunload=function() { void(0) }  
</script>

<script runat="server">
```

then on body called this function

```
<body onload="disableBackButton()">
```

cleared all the seeeions on logout click
then
on page load of admin checked
for session value
if null then return yo login page.Following is the code

```
 protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Session.Clear();

            if (Session["hr"] == null && Session["EMPLOYEEID"]==null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/loginAcc.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["hr"] == null && Session["EMPLOYEEID"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/loginAcc.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If what you're trying to do is just log the user out and clear the session then you are going right around the houses to do it. If your solution replies upon JS for the security of the login then it is very unsecure and you should rethink your approach, or use something like the Membership Provider. And that's not even getting into mentioning how much you really shouldn't be disabling back buttons in browsers.

Comment: clearing the sessions was not enough.bcj one could visit any pageif he knows the url of poage...Thats y i added javascript for that...

Comment: But my point is that if somebody turned the JavaScript off then your back button code does nothing and your solution is ineffective. Also disabling the back button alone does not make the pages secure and anybody can still access them directly.

Comment: Yes. Use Forms Authentication to restrict access to the secure pages as @jayesh goyani suggested, and use the Membership Provider to handle accounts and login and logout. Don't reinvent the wheel unless you have to.